# export pptx by Preserving all the Master Layouts using win32com

Tags: python, powerpoint, pywin32, win32com, python-pptx

I export a slide using win32com

```
for master in presentation.Designs:
    master.Preserved = True

presentation.Slides[1].Export(save_pptx_name, "PPTX")
```

But this option doesn't export the slide with all master layouts.
If I have 3 master layouts, it exports the slide with only 1 master layout, which the slide is using. Other unused master layouts are removed.

I need to preserve all masters.

Comment: Before saving, loop through the Designs collection (ie, your masters) and set each one's Preserved property to True.

Comment: In the input deck, all master slides are already Preserved, isn't that enought @SteveRindsberg

Comment: If this were VBA, it would be; I wonder if this is an obscure bug in the library you're using to control PPT.

Comment: I'm using python; pywin32

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a python user; perhaps someone who's familiar with pywin32 can comment.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg for master in presentation.Designs:
        master.Preserved = True;
added this 2 lines, but didn't help

Comment: You're not working with PPTX files, you're using COM Automation to directly control PowerPoint itself. You're actually calling and executing PowerPoint menus and commands, the same way you would if you were using a VBA macro. You're actually calling [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.export). You can't do anything that PowerPoint itself doesn't allow you to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a template perhaps? There's no expectation to keep unused master slides when exporting a *single* slide - what would be the point? If you want to create a template for presentations, remove all unwanted slides and *save a copy* of the entire presentation to a new location. You can use [Presentation.SaveCopyAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.savecopyas)

Comment: And just for safety, you could call [Presentation.RejectAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.rejectall) after you're done

Comment: Upvoting both of your comments, @PanagiotisKanavos, especially for catching .Export vs .SaveAs.